# Set S3 Buckets defaults before upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cache-control

I want to set S3 bucket defaults, particularly the cache control.
What I need is to set defaults in order to set cache control for all object that will be uploaded to this bucket.

I need a bucket configuration, not a file configuration.

I have seen http://www.bucketexplorer.com/ but this is a paid tool. And only applies the default to files uploaded with this tool.

There is some command or procedure to set the default bucket cache control  previously to file upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no concept in S3 of object defaults at the bucket level.  To the extent a 3rd party tool emulates this, they are doing exactly what you will need to do -- specifying the desired values with each upload of each new object.

Comment: Thanks for response. They are not doing what I need, since I need to upload files to S3 via API, but buckets are not administrated by me and I don't need to know about cache policy in this component.